How to Reduce Latency and Ensure Camera Feed Visibility on Mobile Devices in Low Power Mode?
I'm displaying my camera's feed on a video tag and it works well for the most part. On mobile, I have added logic to swap between the front and rear cameras, which functions correctly. However, I'm facing two issues:

Latency: The time for the video to appear can be quite long, especially when switching between cameras.
Low Power Mode: When the device is in Low Power Mode, the video feed sometimes doesn't appear at all.

  async initCamera() {
    try {
         = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: { facingMode: this.currentFacingMode }, // "user" per default
        audio: false,
      });

      // Set the new stream to the video element and start playing it
      this.video.srcObject = ;
      await this.video.play();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`An error occurred: ${err}`);
    }
  }

  toggleCamera() {
    this.currentFacingMode = this.currentFacingMode === "user" ? "environment" : "user";
    this.initCamera();
  }

